# MySQL Multiple Cursors in Procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, cursors, database-cursor

I've been having problems with my code while trying to understand how Procedures and Cursors in MySQL work. I would like to make so that the cursors use and/or update variables declared in the code, but the only variables updated correctly are var1 and var2. 
Cursor2 should return only 1 result but instead it returns only empty rows, var3 and var4 aren't updated - their values are apparently still the default ones.
Same for Cursor3 and variable var4.

The real code is similar to this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE nameProcedure()

proc_label:BEGIN
DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE var2 VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE var3 INT(3) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var4 int(3) DEFAULT 0;

 // first cursor, gives multiple rows as results 
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1;

 // second cursor, should give only 1 row as result 
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM table2
WHERE column1=var1 
AND column2=var2;

 // third cursor, should give only 1 row as result 
DECLARE cursor3 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT count(column3) 
FROM table3 
WHERE column1=var3;

 // HANDLER 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

OPEN cursor1;
OPEN cursor2;
OPEN cursor3;

label: LOOP 

    FETCH cursor1 INTO var1, var2;

    IF finished=1 THEN LEAVE loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH cursor2 INTO var3, var4;

    IF finished=1 THEN LEAVE proc_label;
    END IF;

    FETCH cursor3 INTO var5;

    IF finished=1 THEN LEAVE proc_label;
    END IF;

    /* UPDATE some rows in tables using the values from var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 in WHERE clauses */

END LOOP loop;

CLOSE cursor1;

CLOSE cursor2;

CLOSE cursor3;

END//
```

I apologize for the writing in this post, English is not my native language and I've never written a post in forums so I'm not sure about how to format it so to make the question more immediately understandable to people. Suggestions, corrections etc. are more than welcome.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what you are trying to do here.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).. Besides MySQL simply supports UPDATE and joining which you try to seam to simulate here.. Something like this is possible in MySQL `UPDATE <...> INNER JOIN table ON <...>  SET <...> WHERE <..>`

Comment: If you change the value of a variable (e.g. var1), it doesn't change the result of your previously defined cursor 2 that used var1. It's not like a script that gets called (and reevaluated) when you fetch the next row. Apart from that: I agree with Raymond, without knowing what you are trying to do, we cannot really fix/answer it. But you should follow his suggestion to read (and then ask) about `join`s: relational databases have the built-in capability to combine rows from different tables; you don't need to manually fetch row 1, look up related data in table 2, fetch row 2, ...